# Copy an instance variable into an Objective-C Block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, instance-variables

I have the following code:

```
- (void)downloadPressed:(id)sender {
    [_download startDownloadWithParser:^id(NSData *rawData) {
        NSString* downloadName = [[_download url] lastPathComponent];

        // ... more code
    }];

    [self reloadView];
}
```

This code is located inside a `UITableViewCell`, and as we all know, the reuse mechanism should be taken very special note of..

**My Question, Clean & Simple:**

If I add the following line of code after the block:

```
_download = nil;
```

The `_download` variable inside the block also gets nil'd! I would like it to get a copy instead, how?

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html): **Within a method implementation, blocks may reference Objective-C instance variables.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you would like your block to get a copy of your ivar, make a local variable from it, and use that local inside your block instead of the ivar:

```
-(void)downloadPressed:(id)sender {
    MyDownload *tmp = _download; // Make an independent pointer
    [tmp startDownloadWithParser:^id(NSData *rawData) { // Use the local
        NSString* downloadName = [[tmp url] lastPathComponent];
        // ... more code
    }];
    [self reloadView];
}
```

The block will capture the value of that local variable at the time the block object is created, making all subsequent changes to `_download` invisible to your block.

Comment: Hah, very nifty .. didn't occur to me. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `MyDownload *tmp = _download;` be prefixed with `__block` nowadays?

Comment: @Bryan You need `__block` only when the code inside the block changes the object the `tmp` references.

Comment: ah, ok cool. But should `tmp` be prefixed with `__block` in that case? Or the value it holds, in this case `_download`?

Comment: @Bryan Assuming that there are no other references of `tmp` inside the `// ... more code` part of the block, the `__block` is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

`_download` in the block is interpreted as `self->_download`, therefore the block captures `self` and not `download`.

This explains why setting  `_download = nil` affects the block, the solution has already been given.

Comment: This is very useful! However, it obscures my understanding of the `__block` specifier.. I thought that it's what allows such mutations?

Comment: `self` is still immutable in the block, but this applies only to the pointer. It does not prevent `self->_download` from being modified.